# Highlight AND Filter Polygon

Tags: tableau-api, dashboard

I have a dashboard where district level data of a country is displayed. I have religion break up on another bar-plot. I have been able to create a dropdown, so that the bar-plot is updated based on selected district.

I also know how to create a dropdown which would highlight the selected district on the map.

How can I create a dropdown which does both - highlights the polygon **AND** updates the bar-plot?

Comment: Have you tried using a Filter action?

Comment: @matt_black yes, in actions, I could only filter _or_ highlight, but not both.